# Is there a pdf reader that displays animations?

Tags: pdf, evince, animations, okular, presentation

I'm creating a presentation and need to include some animations. I placed the animation in the pdf file using Beamer (after storing the animation in a bunch of png files). Now, when I open the file on Okular or Evince, I don't see any animation. Searching around, I read that Evince doesn't support animations but Okular might support them. Is this true? Is there any other tool you can use?

Comment: It is told that Okular PDF is working with it. Try with `sudo apt-get install okular`

Comment: @DuminduMahawela, I tried. The animation doesn't play.

Comment: Have you tried Adobe Acrobat for Linux.

Comment: @Mitch Yes, but it isn't open source. Also, I find it amusing/disturbing that I cannot "enjoy" LaTeX generated files under Linux.

Comment: Please take a look at [this Q&A](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader) over at tex.SE.

Comment: Use adobe reader. It can show animations as well

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Multimedia package to embed movies (mpg, mp4) in a way that you can play them in Okular. Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\begin{document}
\movie[height = 0.6 \textwidth,width = 1.0 \textwidth]{}{animation.mpg}
\end{document}
```

from [Animation in PDF presentations, without Adobe Reader?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429/animation-in-pdf-presentations-without-adobe-reader)

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't really work. The main disadvantage is that the movie doesn't play automatically, but there some other issues as well.

Comment: With TeX Live 2015 and Okular Version 0.24.2 this solution does not work. There are no compilation errors, but Okular only displays a blank space.

Comment: Hi, I've been trying this solution with okular 1.5.3 and TeX Live 2018 and it does not work. After 4 years, do we finally have a working solution to this problem??

Comment: @the.polo sadly no

Comment: @the.polo https://pdfpc.github.io/ always worked well for me. Among other things it has video playback support

Comment: @WaldezJunior Great suggestion. This should be an answer by itself.